# How to search for database\tables in Workbench\j with a hive2 to Hadoop connection?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, sql-workbench-j

Any recommendations on SQL queries to show database or tables in Workbench\j. I got access recently but when I do a SHOW TABLES nothing populates but the query runs. I'm familiar with SQL this my first time in a Hadoop environment. So queries or resources would be very much appreciated. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyuyH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

And

```
USE database;
SHOW TABLES;
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Home#Home-UserDocumentation